# Undeclared variable compid in mariaddb function

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-function

i try to create function to get id of company by phone number(varchar)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIdByPhone (cp CHAR(255))
RETURNS  INT
BEGIN 
SELECT id into compid 
FROM companies 
WHERE comp_phone1=cp;
RETURN compid;
END;
```

and have error:

```
Undeclared variable: compid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you. You need to `declare` the variable before you can assign to it:

```
delimiter //

create function getidbyphone (cp char(255))
returns int
deterministic
begin 
    declare compid int;
    select id into compid from companies where comp_phone1 = cp;
    return compid;
end
//

delimiter;
```

Here is a **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fbyRxrVmDrwHir2vfEyfH5/0)**.

Comment: i tryed it but i still have error: syntax to use near 'en

Comment: @mocart: I fixed a few glitches in the code, and added a link to db fiddle. This does work with your sample data.